# Changes force-pushed to a Mercurial server are not visible there

Tags: mercurial, push, tortoisehg

I have a problem when I'm pushing my code and files to the remote server.
It says that the changes (after they were commited) were pushed successfully onto the remote server but the changes are not visible on the server.

Since I don't have access to the server, how would I go about debugging this problem to find out where the problem occurred (the logs on the server don't show anything I am told)?

Maybe important note:
I had to force push the changes because it wouldn't sent them otherwise.

Second question:
How can I re-push my changes?

Comment: show hg push output here, using --force is bad in common. You can re-push any changesets any time by just push (only *missing in target repo** will be added to it)

Answer (score 1):

If

```
$ hg outgoing
```

shows nothing, then the changes are already there on the server — I promise! If you had access to the server, then running

```
$ hg log
```

would reveal that the changesets are really there. The confusion must be that the *working copy* on the server is not updated when you push changes to it. So someone needs to run

```
$ hg update
```

on the repository on the server to actually make the working copy update. Normally, you don't need a working copy on the server, but if you're using Mercurial to publish, say, a website, then you'll want a push to also update the working copy.

The solution is to add

```
[hooks]
changegroup = hg update
```

to the `.hg/hgrc` file on the server. Maybe you can ask some admin to install that hook for you?

Comment: Was this helpful to you? Then please mark the answer as accepted. If not, then perhaps update your question with more information.